# Solaar Permission Error

Tags: command-line, permissions, error-handling, logitech

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux, and I've tried using Solaar, but I keep getting this Perm Error.
I've tried looking it up already and found some fixes, that being said. I do not know how to follow any of the tutorials I found. (Haven't used much of Terminal yet)

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/udev/rules.d/42-logitech-unify-permissions.rules` and `ls -al /lib/udev/rules.d/60-solaar.rules` and `solaar --version`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit].

Comment: How exactly do I write that command into the terminal? Writing it on it's own doesn't do anything

Comment: See my full installation and setup instructions here: [How do I install and configure the latest version of `solaar` to manage my Logitech wireless mouse or keyboard on Linux Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1390784/327339). You're probably missing your udev rules, which is a step I cover.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS, I suddenly started to have the same error. Upgrading Solaar fixed it, without the need to reboot:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:solaar-unifying/stable
sudo apt update
sudo apt install solaar
```

This upgraded my Solaar version from 1.0.1 to 1.1.8 and it works fine again.

For more info on the latest stable version, see
[https://launchpad.net/~solaar-unifying/+archive/ubuntu/stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Esolaar-unifying/+archive/ubuntu/stable)

And see this comment in the Github issue tracker for more details
https://github.com/pwr-Solaar/Solaar/issues/391#issuecomment-1046388671

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this by updating Ubuntu from 20.04 to 20.1. Took couple of restarts and then somehow solaar worked.